# Create sql Key based on datetime that is persistent overnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a time series with a table like this

```
CarId           
EventDateTime
Event
SessionFlag
```

| CarId | EventDateTime | Event | SessionFlag | ExpectedKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 7:00 | Start | 1 | 1-20220101-7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 7:05 | Drive | 1 | 1-20220101-7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 8:00 | Park | 1 | 1-20220101-7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 10:00 | Drive | 1 | 1-20220101-7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 18:05 | End | 0 | 1-20220101-7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 23:00 | Start | 1 | 1-20220101-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 23:05 | Drive | 1 | 1-20220101-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 2:00 | Park | 1 | 1-20220101-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 3:00 | Drive | 1 | 1-20220101-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 15:00 | End | 0 | 1-20220101-23 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 16:00 | Start | 1 | 1-20220102-16 |

Other CarIds do exist.
What I am attempting to do is create the last column, ExpectedKey.

The problem I face though is midnight, as the same session can exist over two days.
The record above with ExpectedKey 1-20220101-23 is the prime example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I've played with using:

```
CASE 
     WHEN SessionFlag<> 0 
     AND 
     SessionFlag= LAG(SessionFlag) OVER (PARTITION BY Carid ORDER BY EventDateTime) 
THEN FIRST_VALUE(CarId+'-'+Convert(CHAR(8),EventDateTime,112)+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,EventDateTime)AS            
    VARCHAR))OVER (PARTITION BY CarId ORDER BY EventDateTime)
ELSE CarId+'-'+Convert(CHAR(8),EventDateTime,112)+'-'+CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,EventDateTime)AS VARCHAR) END AS SessionId
```

But can't seem to make it partition correctly overnight.

Can anyone off advice?

Comment: Expected results are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.** There are a number of solutions.

The simplest (if not that efficient) is partitioning over a windowed conditional count

```sql
WITH Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Event = 'Start' THEN 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY t.CarId ORDER BY t.EventDateTime)
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT *,
  NewKey = CONCAT_WS('-',
    t.CarId,
    CONVERT(varchar(8), EventDateTime, 112),
    FIRST_VALUE(DATEPART(hour, t.EventDateTime))
      OVER (PARTITION BY t.CarId, t.GroupId ORDER BY t.EventDateTime
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  )
FROM Groups t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ea86056749f04b994f502423f7bb6a3)

Answer (score -1):

using `APPLY` to get the `Start` event datetime and form the key with `concat_ws`

```
select *
from   time_series t
       cross apply
       (
          select top 1 
                 ExpectedKey = concat_ws('-', 
                                         CarId, 
                                         convert(varchar(10), EventDateTime, 112), 
                                         datepart(hour, EventDateTime))
          from   time_series x
          where  x.Event = 'Start'
          and    x.EventDateTime <= t.EventDateTime
          order by x.EventDateTime desc
       ) k
```